# Ruby inject nested loop

Tags: ruby, inject

```
def max_subarr(arr)
  start_index, end_index = 0,
  (0...arr.length).inject([arr.first]) do |max_sub, i|
    (i...arr.length).each do |x|
      if max_sub.inject(:+) < arr[i..x].inject(:+)
        max_sub = arr[i..x]
        start_index, end_index = i, x
      end
    end
    max_sub
  end
  return [start_index, end_index]
end

max_subarr([98, -99, 198, -2, 950]) # => [2,4]
```

Could someone explain why we need the last `max_sub` when we have the `max_sub = arr[i..x]` in the nested loop? And, the function of `inject([arr.first]) do |max_sub, i|`

Answer (score 1):

Sure: that block returns the new value for the memo object. That is, the next value of `max_sub` that is yielded to the block will be whatever that block returned the last time.

And the `inject method of Enumerable` is used to apply a binary operation or an arbitrary block, if provided, to an `Enumerable`.

For each element of the `Enumerable`, `inject` will apply the operation or pass the *memo object* and the current element to the block.

The memo object is either the parameter or, if absent, the first element of the block. It is typically accumulated via a block. Each yield to the block results in a new value of the memo. The last value of the memo object is then returned.

It's a structured and potentially functional way to reduce a data structure to a summary result.

[Full docs here.](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

Comment: I prefer `each_with_object` over `inject` precisely because I don't need to remember to return the new value of memo :)

Comment: @DigitalRoss so max_sub = arr[i..x] would return in the loop of (i...arr.length).each do |x|. And, the last max_sub would return the value bac k to (0...arr.length).inject([arr.first]) do |max_sub, i| ??                I was thinking the value would be assigned and return since max_sub = arr[i..x]

Comment: @paulsus, at this point if you have further questions you should read the docs. Arguably, you should have done that before posting, lol.